# Two column layout with self-contained fixed-position sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, web-component

I need a two-column layout, where the left (sidebar) is fixed and the right (main content) is scrollable.

I've done so with bootstrap's flex grid/layout:

```css
#left { width: 10rem; }
#right { margin-left: 10rem; }           /* <------------- PROBLEM */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row g-0">
  <nav id="left" class="col vh-100 position-fixed bg-success">test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</nav>
  <main id="right" class="col bg-warning">START test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test FINISH</main>
</div>
```

The problem is the right column knows about the left column's width. I tried bootstrap's `col-auto` but that doesn't help.

In reality, the left column is an imported sidebar component, which is self-contained. So the rest of my design (and the right column) should not have any knowledge of its dimensions. For example:

```html
<div class="container">
  <sidebar />
  <main id="right"><!-- whatever --></main>
</div>
```

*How can I change this layout so the sidebar's width is not needed by the rest of the design?* Is that even possible?

Note:

- It doesn't need to be in bootstrap (it can be plain css)
- There's no JavaScript in my wasm SPA framework, so I can't use it (and regardless, it must be a self-contained component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an over simplified example with just plain CSS.

It uses `position: sticky` instead of `fixed` on `#left`. This way, `#left` gets both its place in the flow, and get `fixed` as a result.

This should allow `#right` to auto-fill the rest of space with `flex: 1`, without a hard coded `width` from `#left`.

Hope it gets the desired result correctly.

Example:

```css
/* Try any value  */
#left { width: 10rem }
/* Auto-fill  */
#right { flex: 1 }

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
}

main {
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<nav id="left">test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</nav>
<main id="right">START test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test FINISH</main>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks John! I never thought to use `sticky`. This is good because the sidebar's width is set in one place, and the rest of the layout adjusts automatically. So the sidebar could be a self-contained web component and I just drop it into my layout without any extra work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure i understood you question correctly. If not, maybe you could add some kind of image to better show what you want to do?

If you want a 2 layout column, where the left sidebar is fixed, maybe something like this would work:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding;
  0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  position: relative;
}

.col {
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.col--left {
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.col--right {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row g-0">
  <nav id="left" class="col col--left">SIDEBAR test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</nav>
  <main id="right" class="col col--right">START test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test testtest test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test testtest test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test testtest test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test FINISH</main>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Boguz! I've never used css grid, so please forgive my ignorance. Where is the left column's width set? Am I right in assuming that it's `10rem`? Because in that case the width is set on the container (rather than the sidebar component itself), which means it isn't in control of its own dimensions. From what little I understand of css grids, I believe the width is set outside the grid item, so I'm unsure whether this is a viable solution? Thank you very much regardless, you've given me much to think about!

Comment: Yes, i had defined it on the container. But you can also very easily define it on the component itself. I have updated my answer so you can see what i mean